# Synclient touchpad settings for ClickFinger3 constantly resetting

Tags: xubuntu, touchpad, multi-touch, system-settings

I'm using Xubuntu 16.10

I'm trying to set a 3 finger click to a middle click. When I run synclient ClickFinger3=2, it works for approximately 5 seconds, than automatically gets switched back to 1. TapButton3=2 is working perfectly fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, it was happening due to [xSwipe](https://github.com/iberianpig/xSwipe)